# NX: How to build all libraries belonging to a grouping folder

Tags: angular, build, monorepo, nrwl-nx, libs

I have developed a library "A" made of several modules ("x", "y", "z") with the following folders structure:

```
project
 + apps
 - libs
   + A
   - B
     - x
       - src
         - lib
            + components
            + services
              x.module.ts
     + y
     + z
   + C
```

I can build each module of the library with the following command: `nx build @A/x`

Does exist a command to build the whole "A"?

I have found `nx run-many --target=build --projects=A:x,A:y,A:z` but I'm afraid is not applicable in my case due the file and folder structure I have given to my library.

Generally speaking, what is the best practice in case of modular library or a library that have a grouping folder like mine?

Comment: Is there a natural root/principle/core library? If so you can add the others to this on via [implicitDependancies](https://nx.dev/more-concepts/how-project-graph-is-built#how-the-project-graph-is-built) and building the root/principle/core library will build the others if you have `"targetDefaults": { "build": { "dependsOn": ["^build"], ... },` inside `nx.json`. Here `^build` means the dependents libraries